# Copy block of code with increasing index

Tags: vim

I have the following function declaration:

```
function f1(s)
real f1,s
f1 = 1/s
end
```

I would like to copy the same block but with increasing function name, i.e. `f1, f2, f3, ...` in order to get this:

```
function f1(s)
real f1,s
f1 = 1/s
end

function f2(s)
real f2,s
f2 = 1/s
end

function f3(s)
real f3,s
f3 = 1/s
end
```

My present approach is to copy the block in visual mode, paste it several times and then rename the functions manually. I would like to know how to achieve this faster using Vim. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use a recording (see `:h recording`). Assuming you have a blank line before and after your function **and no blank lines in between**

```
// empty line here, cursor here
function f1(s)
real f1,s
f1 = 1/s
end
// empty line here
```

With the cursor on the empty line above, make a recording to any register you like. Here I'm using register `c`. Press <kbd>qc</kbd> then press `y}}Pjw*Ne^Ane^Ane^A{` and exit with `q`.

**Explanation**

- `y}` - yank next paragraph
- `}` - move down one paragraph
- `P` - put above this line
- `j` - move one line done
- `w` - move to next word
- `*` - search for word under cursor ( this is the function name here)
- `N` - search backwards ( we moved with `*` to get the pattern into the register )
- `e` - go to end of word
- `^A` - <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd> to increase the number
- `n` - go to next match / search forward ( this is the function name )
- `e` - go to end of word
- `^A` - increase the number
- `n` - go to next match / search forward
- `e` - go to end of word
- `^A` - increase the number
- `{` - move up one paragraph (same relative position as in the beginning, but at the inserted function f2 )

Now you can use `@c` to copy the function and increase all numbers. Prefix with the count you want, e.g. `5@c` will copy the function 5 times and adjust the numbering.

In case you don't want to remember the string `y}}Pjw*Ne^Ane^Ane^A{` you can paste it in the vim buffer. You will have to replace the `^A` before yanking though. Delete `^A` and when in insert mode press <kbd>Ctrl v</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>. ( If you are inside a screen session you will have to press <kbd>Ctrl a</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, this is `CTRL-a` and `a`)

With the cursor on the line in normal mode press `"cY` to yank it in register c.

Then you can replay it with `@c`.

This way you can also modify it or yank it to another register.

Use `let @c=y}}Pjw*Ne^Ane^Ane^A{` in your `.vimrc` to have it always load to register `c` when starting vim.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution. It may seems complex but does not, cause you have just to copy this function to the clipboard and load the function with:

```
:@+
```

Below the function with additional features

```
fun! CopyAndIncrease()
    try
        let l:old_copy = getreg('0')
        normal yip
        let @0 = substitute(@0,'\d\+','\=submatch(0) + 1','g')
        exec "normal }O\<Esc>p"
    finally
        call setreg('0', l:old_copy)
    endtry
endfun
command! -nargs=0 CopyIncrease silent call CopyAndIncrease() | exec "normal \<Esc>"
let mapleader = ','
nnoremap <Leader>c :CopyIncrease<CR>
```

Now pressing `,c` Now you can use the keybinding and commands defined in the function.

Function's explanation:

```
let l:old_copy = getreg('0') -> save copy register
normal yip  ->  copy block
let @0 ... increase numbers on copy register
exec "normal }O\<Esc>p" -> paste increased block
```